# Merge tags: [attributerouting] and [attributerouting.net]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The [attributerouting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributerouting) and [attributerouting.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributerouting.net) tags should be merged.

Answer (score 3):

The ".net" suffix seems completely and utterly superfluous. Fortunately, there were only six questions with that tag, so it was easy enough for me to retag by hand.